# Parsing through Retrofit and set Data to the Base Adapter

Tags: android

I am working with `Retrofit` (`JSON` Parsing Android) and I am new with this I am so confused to set the response with the Base Adapter.

This is my Example Class

```
public class Example {

@SerializedName("Totalrecord")
@Expose
private List<Totalrecord> totalrecord = null;
@SerializedName("Table1")
@Expose
private List<Table1> table1 = null;
@SerializedName("Table2")
@Expose
private List<Table2> table2 = null;

public List<Totalrecord> getTotalrecord() {
    return totalrecord;
}

public void setTotalrecord(List<Totalrecord> totalrecord) {
    this.totalrecord = totalrecord;
}

public List<Table1> getTable1() {
    return table1;
}

public void setTable1(List<Table1> table1) {
    this.table1 = table1;
}

public List<Table2> getTable2() {
    return table2;
}

public void setTable2(List<Table2> table2) {
    this.table2 = table2;
}
}
```

Here I am trying to retrieve Response in `ArrayList` so that I can set it to `Adapter`

```
    ApiService api = RetroClient.getApiService();
            Call<Example> call = api.getMyJson(38, 109);
            call.enqueue(new Callback<Example>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<Example> call, Response<Example> response) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                    if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                   //     Response_list = response.body().get...
                        adapter_view = new Adapter_view(Response_list, MainActivity.this);
                        listView.setAdapter(adapter_view);
                    }
                }
                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<Example> call, Throwable t) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                    System.out.println("failed");
                }
            });
```

But I am confused to set The type of `ArrayList` and also Type of `Callback<>` so that I can get the response properly and set `ArrayList` to the `Adapter`.

Comment: `Example example = response.body()`??

Answer (score 0):

try following if you want to set `List<Totalrecord>` in your `adapter`.

```
ApiService api = RetroClient.getApiService();
            Call<Example> call = api.getMyJson(38, 109);
            call.enqueue(new Callback<Example>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<Example> call, Response<Example> response) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                    if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                   Response_list.clear();
                   Response_list.addAll(call.getTotalrecord());
                        adapter_view = new Adapter_view(Response_list, MainActivity.this);
                        listView.setAdapter(adapter_view);
                    }
                }
                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<Example> call, Throwable t) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                    System.out.println("failed");
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
List<Table1> mList=new ArrayList();
ApiService api = RetroClient.getApiService();
        Call<Example> call = api.getMyJson(38, 109);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<Example>() {
        @Override
  public void onResponse(Call<Example> call, Response<Example> response) {
                dialog.dismiss();
                if (response.body.isSuccessful()) {
                   mList=response.body.getTable1();
                   adapter_view = new Adapter_view(mList,MainActivity.this);
                    listView.setAdapter(adapter_view);
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<Example> call, Throwable t) {
                dialog.dismiss();
                System.out.println("failed");
            }
        });
```

Comment: Good Morning, Thanks for Your reply and see this is my JSON response {
"Totalrecord":[
{
"TotalClient":10
}
],
"Table1":[
{
"TotalCompleted":7
}
],
"Table2":[
{
"GSTRName":"GSTR-1",
"RecordNo":1
},
{
"GSTRName":"GSTR-2",
"RecordNo":3
},
{
"GSTRName":"GSTR-3",
"RecordNo":6
},
{
"GSTRName":"GSTR-3B",
"RecordNo":21
}
]
}   and if I take arraylist of <Example> type then it is not generating response like the above and if I take arraylist of <Table1> type then its response will be only of Table1 's records

Comment: Hi Nidhi, don't need to take array list of <Example> just do simple one thing like this mTable1List=response.body.getExample.getTable1 mTable2List=response.body.getExample.getTable2 mTotalRecordList=response.body.getExample.getTotalRecord

Comment: Ok sir, but in this condition I am having 3 to 4 records but in the condition when I'll have more then 10 records it will be so lengthy.

Comment: i think we haven't any problem even with more records because we have a list of every objects models. It can contain many records.

Comment: Please dont write words like goood morning , thanks etc. and dont put coding related stuff in comment. you can explain your anwser with EDIT